# Convert Grub4Dos Volume to NTFS

Tags: partition, convert

I can't run Windows Backup because one of the critical volumes is not NTFS.
I have identified the partition, but I want to make sure it is safe to convert to NTFS.

I have 3 partitions:

1. System Reserve (D:) NTFS  (Primary Partition)
2. Grub4DOS_BOOT (B:) FAT32  (System, Active, Primary Partition)
3. C Drive (C:) NTFS (Boot, Primary Partition)

I know Grub4DOS can be installed on a NTFS partition, but I can't find anything that confirms you can convert Grub4DOS from FAT32 to NTFS.

If it did fail, would the system still boot using the System Reserve partition or would I need to make it Active first?

Thanks
Mike